# find the mapping of the given bilinear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Q)find the bilinear transformation which maps the points $~z=1,~i,~1~$ and $~w =i,~o,~-i~$.hence find the image of $~|z|<1~$

by using the cross ratio for bilinear transformation ,I've managed the answer $$w=\frac
{Zi+1}{Zi-1}~.$$
I am unable to go with the second part of the problem i.e., $~|z|<1~$.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=\frac{iz+1}{iz-1}$ and $w=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ and  $z=\frac{-w-i}{w-i}$
. $|z|<1$  is equivalent to

\begin{align*}
|w+i|&<|w-i|\\
|u+iv+i|&<|u+iv-i|
\end{align*}

Simplifying this ,we get $v<0$  (i.e) $\text{Im}\,w<0$. Indeed 
$|z|<1$ maps $\text{Im}\,w<0$